# Chrome and IE refuse to open any Google app like Google+ or Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-connection

Chrome and IE refuse to open any Google app like Google+ or Chrome Web Store but the funny thing is Mozilla can access all the pages, even Chrome Web Store. When I use Chrome it shows "This web page is not available" and Internet Explorer keeps loading forever.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really provide enough information to recommend anything here, but I'll stab at it for good measure: It kinda sounds like there's a proxy set in IE and Chrome that is not set in FF or vice versa, so check those settings.

Comment: Chrome uses whatever proxy is set in IE, so yeah it's fair to say this is what's happening

Comment: no the proxy is fine because chrome and IE opens all other sites other than google code,google plus, google web store, and also i cannot even sych chrome to my account (it logs into my accounts and stucks on synching).

Answer (score 0):

no the proxy is fine because chrome and IE opens all other sites other than google code,google plus, google web store, and also i cannot even sych chrome to my account (it logs into my accounts and stucks on synching).

Comment: am sorry guys i accidenty posted the comment on the answer window? and i dont see remove answer link.

Comment: Guys Thank u anyways i found out it was something else i have no clue what but i updated my windows to windows service pack 1 and now everything works great.